# Haskell -- Sums Accumulated in Lists

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, cumulative-sum

I need to create or know if there is a function in Haskell that allows you to add items from a list. So, for example:

```
cumulativeAmount :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

cumulativeAmount [1,2,5,8,8,0,4,2] = [1,3,8,16,24,24,28,30]

cumulativeAmount [1,4,7,0,5] = [1, 1+4, 1+4+7, 1+4+7+0, 1+4+7+0+5] = [1,5,12,12,17]
```

I tried to use the `map` and `scanl` function, but I didn't get what I wanted, because I added all the elements.

Comment: I suggest you write it yourself. Did you try that?

Comment: What was it that you tried with `scanl`?

Comment: `scanl` (or `scanl1`) seems the right tool for this job. I'd suggest to insist on that route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of [**`scanl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl1):

```
Prelude> scanl1 (+) [1,2,5,8,8,0,4,2]
[1,3,8,16,24,24,28,30]
```

`scanl1` takes as input a function `f :: a -> a -> a` (here `(+)`), and a list of `a`s. It constructs a list where the first item is the first item of the list. This is the first value of the *accumulator*. Then for every value, the accumulator is updated by calling `f` with the accumulator and the next value of the list, this item is then yielded.

So in case of `scal1 (+) [1,2,5]` the first item we emit is `1`, we also set the accumulator to `1`. The next item is `2`, so we call `(+) 1 2` (which is `3`) and this is the result and the new accumulator, next we call `(+) ((+) 1 2) 5` (which is `8`), etc.

But I think it is better, as an exercise to use recursion. Like said before we use an accumulator. We can implement this by introducing an extra function where the accumulator is a function we pass through the recursive calls (and update). So in that case it looks like:

```
cumulativeAmount :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
cumulativeAmount [] = ...
cumulativeAmount (x:xs) = go x xs
    where go x xs = ...
```

so here the first argument of `go` (`x`) is the accumulator. I leave it as an exercise to implement it with recursion.

Comment: What do you think of something like: `cumulativeAmount' = map sum . tail . inits`? Would you consider this to be pretty inefficient?

Comment: @RoadRunner: yeah, since the time complexity is O(n^2), not O(n).

Answer (score 4):

What about using an accumulator:

```
cumulativeAmount :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
cumulativeAmount xs = go xs 0
    where go [] acc = []
          go (x:xs) acc = (acc+x) : go xs (acc+x)
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> cumulativeAmount [1,2,5,8,8,0,4,2]
[1,3,8,16,24,24,28,30]
```

The above code keeps a state variable `acc` to accumulate sums whenever a new number is encountered, and adds the new sum to the resulting list.

Now a good exercise would be to replace the above code with higher order functions.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, you could solve this with a list comprehension, like so:

```
cumulativeAmount xs = [ sum $ take x xs | x <- [1..length xs] ]
```

Comment: This is actually quite inefficient: since it means that calculating the *i*-th item, will not reduce the cost of calculating the *i+1*-th item. Furthermore it uses `length` which means we first will calculate `xs`, this can again be troublesome since it can blow up memory, and it is possible that the list has infinite length.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't actually test the code or think much about the efficiency; I just brought to bear the first solution that I could think of. From other comments, looks like scanl is what one should use.